# trigger bindingHandler on href click with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm using KnockoutJS and i've created a custom handler for it.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.customHandler = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        // init code
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        // Also called when first loaded...
        // Also called when clicked
    }
};
```

This all works when i bind it to an input element:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="customHandler: true" />
```

But not when i add it to a hyperlink

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-bind="customHandler: true" />
```

Is there a way to easily bind my custom handler to an `a href`?

Comment: why do you want an href? why not just a click event with a hash `#` in the href?

Comment: @deltree Because some other `input` element also triggers that handler. I also need a `link` to trigger the same handler when its clicked. It may sounds strange, but i really do need that functionality.

Comment: can you put together a JSFiddle, you don't have any functionality here, so it's hard for me to see what issue you're having.